# Validation rule for end date and open date

Tags: validation

I have real time scenario which i am facing now is that there are 2 fields, open date and end date respectively. when a user enter end date one should get an error that must enter open date when you mention an end date.

kindly help me out.

Answer (score 1):

You can use validation rule to prevent saving of the records when record has end date without start date.
`NOT(ISNULL(End Date)) && ISNULL(Start Date)`  Please use API names for Start Date and End Date in the validation rule.

Answer (score 0):

Write a validation rule such that.

if(endDate != null and openDate = null, true, false)

in the message part Open date is required.